# Closed form for a minimum related to Khintchine inequality

Tags: probability-theory, analysis, inequality, optimization, closed-form

Let $p>2$ be a real number.

In [this blog post](https://almostsuremath.com/2020/08/04/the-khintchine-inequality/) by George Lowther, a proof of the right-hand [Khintchine inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khintchine_inequality) is given where
$$m_p:=\min_{x>0}\;x^{-p}\cosh(x)$$
comes into play.

**Question:** Is it possible to express $m_p$ in closed form?

**Remark:** According to the proof given in this post, the best right-hand constant in Khintchine inequality is bounded above by
$$K_p:=\frac{p^{-p/2}e^{p/2}}{m_p}.$$
So what I'm really interested in is the value of $K_p$ for $p>2$.

Comment: Note $(x^{-p}\cosh x)'=(x\tanh x-k)x^{-p-1}\operatorname{sech}x$ so minimum occurs when $x\tanh x=k$ - see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1091611/solve-x-tanhx-constant).